# $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x) =0$ but $\displaystyle\lim_ {x\to\infty} f(x)\neq0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\neq0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Let $f$ e $g$ continuous functions, from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x) =0$ but $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\neq0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\neq 0$.

I experimented with $f(x)=\max\{\sin x, 0\}$ and $g(x)=\min\{\sin x, 0\}$, clearly you have to $\forall x\in\mathbb R \, f(x)g(x)=0 $, so $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)g(x)=0$, but you don't have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ (consider $a_n=2n\pi-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\lim f(a_n)=1$, similarly there is no $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}g( x)\neq0$.

My question is, are there "simpler" functions than this example?

Comment: $f(x)=1,g(x)=-1$ for the case of $f+g$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, for your $f$ it is incorrect to say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\ne0$, because the limit does not exist to begin with, so it cannot be compared to $0$. The situation is indeed only possible if at least one of the functions has no limit at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what "simpler" should mean here. I immediately thought along similar lines as you did in order to construct an example.

When it comes to $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)+g(x)=0$ while $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq0\neq\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$, this is even easier. Take $f$ an arbitrary continuous function with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq0$ and put $g(x)=-f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extreme case where $f(x)g(x)$ is identically $0$!. Let $C=\bigcup_n [2n,2n+1]$ and $D=\bigcup_n [2n-1,2n]$. Then $C$ and $D$ are closed sets. Define $f(x)=d(x,C)$ [$=\inf\{|x-y|: y \in C\}$] and $g(x)=d(x,D)$. Then $f(x)g(x)=0$ for all $x$ but $f(2n+\frac 3  2)=\frac 1  2$ for all $n$, $g(2n+\frac 1  2)=\frac 1  2$ for all $n$ so $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not tend to $0$.

For the case of $f+g$ take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=-1$.